# How to customize the Animation of the Circular CountDownTimer

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to customize the [`CircularCountdownTimer`](https://pub.dev/packages/circular_countdown_timer) so that you can run it without a limited duration. After one hour the ring should be completely filled and the animation should start again from 0 after 1 hour. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is my code

```dart
import 'package:circular_countdown_timer/circular_countdown_timer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  CountDownController controller = CountDownController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            CircularCountDownTimer(
              width: 300,
              height: 300,
              duration: 60,
              fillColor: Colors.blue,
              ringColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.25),
              autoStart: false,
              controller: controller,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    controller.start();
                  },
                  child: const Text("Start"),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    controller.pause();
                  },
                  child: const Text("Pause"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample code you've written,  Find more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Here is the link to the code: https://github.com/jjklangbehn/animationproblem/blob/main/main.dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onComplete` to restart the animation.

```dart
CircularCountDownTimer(
  width: 300,
  height: 300,
  duration: 60, // it is on seconds,
  fillColor: Colors.blue,
  ringColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.25),
  autoStart: false,
  controller: controller,
  onComplete: () {
    controller.restart();
  },
),
```